# Сборка программы для 64-битной системы из-под 32-битной

Tags: c#, компиляция, сборка

Пишу программу на C# с использованием SQLite (или SQL Compact Edition) в 32-битной системе, а надо ее собрать для целевого компьютера с 64-битной системой.
Возможно ли такое сделать? И каким образом?

Comment: вообще говоря, при сборке указывается для какой платформы собирается

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для этого компилятору нужно указать, что вы хотите собирать проекты(ы) под 64-битную систему. Это можно сделать несколькими способами:

- В командной строке компилятора указать дополнительный
  параметр `/platform:x64`
- В Visual Studio для сборки всего солюшна: Debug -> Configuration
  Manager, дальше в списке Active Solution Platforms выбрать x64. Если
  ее нет, нажать  и в диалоге выбрать тип x64.
- В Visual Studio для сборки конкретного проекта: зайти в свойства
  проекта, на закладке Build выбрать в Platform Target значение x64.

Но вообще говоря, если вы разрабатываете в 32-битной системе, то для запуска приложения под 64-битную ОС достаточно выбрать конфигурацию x86 и скачать пакет SQLite такой же битности.

Если вам все же нужен настоящий x64, то как вариант в проекте у вас может быть подключен x86 SQLite, а x64 SQLite пусть лежит где-то рядом. В post build event вы можете проверять битность, и если это x64, то вычищаете скопированные x86 библиотеки и копируете x64 библиотеки. Плюс почитайте [документацию к SQLite](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki), там оговорены эти моменты.

Comment: Ясно. А как быть со SQLite (или SQL Compact Edition)?

Comment: @GhostBasenji в смысле?

Comment: В прямом смысле... SQLite(или SQL Compact Edition) придется брать 64. По-моему, их никак не собрать под 64.

Comment: @GhostBasenji обновил ответ. Но имейте в виду, что библиотеку SQLite я никогда не использовал, опираюсь на общие соображения.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы используете официальную [System.Data.SQLite](https://system.data.sqlite.org/), то проще всего подключить NuGet-пакет [System.Data.SQLite.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite.Core) или [System.Data.SQLite](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite) (если вам нужна поддержка LINQ и EF6). В описании сказано:

> The official SQLite database engine for both x86 and x64 along with the ADO.NET provider.

Т.е. оба этих пакета идут с нативными `SQLite.Interop.dll` обеих версий (x86 и x64), при сборке AnyCPU в `bin` копируются обе dll-ки, а managed-обертка `System.Data.SQLite.dll` при запуске уже сама выбирает, какую нативную библиотеку грузить. То есть не надо париться - работает само.

Менять `Target Platform` с дефолтного `AnyCPU` при этом не нужно.